# Detokenize input to \newcommand

Tags: listings, xstring, underscore, detokenize

I would like to define a command that removes .m when referencing to the caption `generate_simdata.m` (i have a lot of such matlab function files, and would like to reference them normally with `\nameref` (as files) and also reference them without the file extension, when talking about them as function and not as files). My attempt in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\baseref}[1]{
\hyperref[#1]{\texttt{\StrBetween{\detokenize{#1}}{lst:}{.m}}}
}
```

In the main file:

```
\baseref{lst:generate_simdata.m}
```

Where i would like it to be replaces with a link to the listing, where the link is named `generate_simdata`, instead of `generate_simdata.m` which `\nameref` produces. I tried without `\detokenize` --- it worked, but the underscore was not parsed correctly.

At the bottom of the main file:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption=\texttt{generate\_simdata.m}, label={lst:generate_simdata.m}]{MatLab/generate_simdata.m}
```

Comment: Can you please show a minimal document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: you could do that but why not use the simpler definition and simpler input `\baseref{generate_simdata}` and use something like  `\hyperref[lst:#1.m]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}` ie adding the .m where needed rather than removing it where it is not?